# Node's promisify is not working with callback-based function

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am having a function which does some async processing and I want to convert it to a promise, so that I can make a "chain of execution" with other depended functions later on.

Below is the code(slightly modified for privacy):

```
router.get('/api/prx/ptr', function(req, res) {
    let prx = req.params.prx_id
    let ptr = {}    

    let parse_text = (idx_array, prx) => {
        for(let name of idx_array) {
            if (typeof ptr[name] === 'undefined') {
                ptr[name] = []
            }
            get_text(prx, name, (tg) => {
                const pst = new Set(tg.ph.map(ps => ps.label))
                pst.forEach(ps => {
                    ptr[name].push(ps)
                })
            })
        }
        return true
    }

    parse_text = promisify(parse_text)

    documentExists(prx, function(err, dbexists){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(404).send(err)
        }

        get_idx_array(prx, function(err, idx_array){
            if (err) {
                return res.status(err.code || 400).send(err)
            }

            idx_array = idx_array.map(function(v){return v._id});

            parse_text(idx_array, prx)
            .then(result => {
                res.status(200).send(ptr)
            })
        })
    })
})
```

The problem is that in the last line, the promise never resolves and thus the request-response cycle never ends. Not sure what I have done wrong in my setup. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `get_text` looks to be the *actual* asynchronous function here, not `parse_text`. Also, try putting a `catch` after your `then`, it'll probably show a problem.

Comment: So do you suggest to promisify get_text instead?

Comment: I think so, because otherwise the asynchronous callback inside `parse_text` won't be properly chained with the outside consumer of `parse_text`

Comment: Makes sense to try :)